# Geo-Fencing using Google Map in iPhone

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to Geo-fence using `Google Map` for `iPhone` app.
A lot of tutorials can be found for MKMapView. But can't find for the GMSMapView.
The basic thing is how to convert the screen coordinate (x,y) to the MapCoordinate lat/lng.
Is there any `API` available for Google Map in `iOS` for that conversion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
GMSMapView* mapView = ...;
CGPoint point = ...;
...
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = 
    [mapView.projection coordinateForPoint: point];
```

**UPDATE:**

The comments on the `projection` property in `GMSMapView.h` are:

```
/**
 * The GMSProjection currently used by this GMSMapView. This is a snapshot of
 * the current projection, and will not automatically update when the camera
 * moves. The projection may be nil while the render is not running (if the map
 * is not yet part of your UI, or is part of a hidden UIViewController, or you
 * have called stopRendering).
 */
@property (nonatomic, readonly) GMSProjection *projection;
```

Therefore you can only access the `.projection` property after the map has rendered. It will be nil if you try to access it during `loadView` or `viewDidLoad`.

I don't know if there is a better way to tell if the map has been rendered, but I noticed that the `mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:` method is called once after the map view is first displayed, and that the map's `projection` property is valid there.

So, in your view controller's header, add `GMSMapViewDelegate`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GMSMapViewDelegate>
```

When you allocate the map view, assign the delegate:

```
_map = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height) camera: camera]; 
_map.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview: _map];
```

Then add the delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView: (GMSMapView*)mapView
    didChangeCameraPosition: (GMSCameraPosition*)position
{
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(x, y); 
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = 
        [_map.projection coordinateForPoint: point];
}
```

Note that `mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:` is called every time the user changes the camera, so you'd probably need to use a flag, so that you only do your calculations the first time `mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:` is called.

Comment: I did as follow, but I got 0 for both latitude and longitude.    CGPoint newpoint = CGPointMake(startX, startY);
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self.map.projection coordinateForPoint: newpoint];

Comment: Can you do an `NSLog` of `self.map` and `self.map.projection`, to make sure they're not nil? Maybe also check `self.map.projection.visibleRegion` (and log all four corners - eg `.nearLeft .nearRight .farLeft .farRight`), to see if the numbers seem sensible? At what point are you doing the calculation - would the map view have been fully initialized by then?

Comment: @ Saxon Druce I logged and I got the following. self.map.projection has 0x0                                                            2013-03-02 14:09:21.701 TrackMe[3632:907] self.map 0x1c52e6f0
2013-03-02 14:09:21.706 TrackMe[3632:907] self.map.projection 0x0

Comment: @ Saxon Druce MapView is fully initialized and I can see the map on the view. I load the map as follow.                   GMSCameraPosition *default_loc = [GMSCameraPosition        cameraWithLatitude:16.8
                                                                 longitude:96.15
                                                                      zoom:5];
    _map = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:default_loc];
    _map.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    _map.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:_map];

Comment: I tried like                                       MKMapPoint newpoint = MKMapPointMake(startX, startY);
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(newpoint);I got the coordinate but it is lat is 85 and long is -180. But my map view Center is lat 16.8 and long 96.15 at zoom 5.

Comment: `MKMapPoint` is a 2D projection where the whole world (up to +/- 85 degrees latitude) is covered by an image with width and height of (256 << 20) pixels. So it's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks like the projection is nil. The `GMSMapView.h` header says that projection may be nil if the renderer is not running. Are you trying to get the projection within loadView, or some time after the map has been rendered (like on a button tap)?

Comment: I implemented CGPoint a = CGPointMake(startX, startY);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self.map.projection coordinateForPoint: a]; in the ViewDidLoad. [self.view addSubview:_map]; is also inside in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: Hi @Bryanyan, the projection will be nil in `viewDidLoad`. I've added an update which describes a way to get a valid projection, after the map has been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

**`No need to convert x,y to lat,long.`**

```
GMSCircle *fence = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:locationCord radius:fenceRadius];
    [fence setFillColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255 green:178.0/255 blue:255.0/255 alpha:0.3]];
    [fence setZIndex:100];

    [fence setMap: _map];
```

Add this code when you are making GMSMapView and geo fence will be shown with your location marker.